# Are docstrings in wordpress of any use?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, docstring

```
/**
 * Retrieves the post excerpt.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @since 4.5.0 Introduced the `$post` parameter.
 *
 * @param int|WP_Post $post Optional. Post ID or WP_Post object. Default is global $post.
 * @return string Post excerpt.
 */
function get_content_excerpt( $post = null ) {
```

I found these docstrings on top of a function in "functions.php" of my Wordpress website. Firstly, are these called "docstrings"?. Secondly, does removing this cause any issue in the functioning.
Please explain its importance. I have found no resources that answer my question.

Comment: https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/what-is-a-docblock.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to are DocBlocks and are a part of WordPress' PHP Documentation Standards: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/php/

You can read more about the system that it's based on here: https://phpdoc.org/

In short, they're a standardised form of code documentation that can be interpreted and used in a number of ways. Your IDE for instance may be capable of displaying that information as part of its intellisense.

> Secondly, does removing this cause any issue in the functioning.

Removing DocBlocks shouldn't cause anything to break but I can't see a valid reason for doing so.